# how to change the dynamic URL to SEO friendly using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change the dynamic URL `www.example.com/business-listing.php?id=7863` to `www.example.com/some-dynamic-text/7863`.

Also I want to hide .php extension from all URL, for eg: the URL `www.example.com/list/page.php`  should be change to `www.example.com/list/page`

And also when an user enter the URL `www.example.com/list/page.php`, he should restricted to access that page using that URL. Permit acess only using

```
www.example.com/list/page
```

I have tried the following .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_,-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_,-]+)$ business-listing.php?id=$1
```

1. This take the first regular expression as value of id, but I want the Second.
2. This hide the php extension of only home.php, but I want all php files.
3. This does not  prevent the user when entering the URL with PHP extension, That is when an user enter the URL `www.example.com/bill/pay.php` the page is open, but I want to restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(*\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^/?([^\./]*)[:;,\.]*$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^list/(.*)$ business-listing.php?id=$1
```

If you want the 'list' part of the URL dynamic, try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ business-listing.php?id=$2
```

Comment: This is working. But have 2 problems:   1. Hiding .php extension does not work for PHP files in sub directories. 2. Does not prevent access to php files using original URL(Question No:3)

Comment: Why do you want to prevent to access the original URL?

Comment: OK, you can block the URL's before you start the rewrite. See edit.

Comment: I want to block all PHP files, and allow access through the filename without the PHP extension.

Comment: for eg: the URL www.example.com/login.php shoul be accessed using only www.example.com/login

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ business-listing.php?id=$2&second=$2 [R,NC,L]
```

Try this!

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it using .htaccess. Migration to nginx will be very painful in this case. Also you should remember of [Front Controller Pattern](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

URL should be processed by PHP(python, ryby etc...). There is variety of ready frameworks for url routing and a lot of cool things, like database api or template engine. In the php-world there are a lot of variants.As for me, I prefer [Silex microframework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) and [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/).
[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and [Zend2](http://framework.zend.com/) are worth seeing too.

For example, in silex you can bind a function to url-pattern in such a nice way:

```
// web/index.php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
});

$app->run();
```

Good luck.

Comment: First off all, if your site gets huge auditory, you will have to use nginx as frontend to apache. Nginx's config syntax differs from apache2's one. That's why migration promises to be painfull. Secondly, if you use .htaccess, your application will have will have multiple front controllers, instead of a single one. This may lead some security problems(Cause probability of error increases with number of front controllers.) There must be a single script operating ALL requests(This does not mean that all your code must be in a single file).

Comment: [Why use front controller](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/FrontController.htm)(see Forces)

Comment: I cant understand anything you commented

Comment: Ok, read [this](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html)  and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). And try to read Head First Desighn patterns and Martin Fowler's Patterns of enterprise application architecture.